# How to retrieve <servlet><init-param> value from web.xml in Servlet?

Tags: servlets, web.xml, init-parameters

I need to retrieve init-param value from xml to Servlet i used following code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jdbcDriver</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

servlet code

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    System.out.println(config.getInitParameter("jdbcDriver"));
}
```

But It displayed null .. could any one help me to do that .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I can't see a single reason, why you have to override your `init(ServletConfig sc)` method, since you can always get your `ServletConfig` by calling your inherited `getServletConfig()` method.

```
System.out.println(getServletConfig().getInitParameter("jdbcDriver"));
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you have custom initialization work to do, override the no-arg
>   init() method, and forget about init(ServletConfig). Is it ok to call
>   getServletConfig() method inside the no-arg init() method? Yes, an
>   instance of ServletConfig has already been saved by superclass
>   GenericServlet.

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/common-mistake-in-servlet-init-methods.html

It is always good to use packages for classes. It enables clear demarcation.

Answer (score 0):

um... it should work.
Are you calling the code in LoginServlet? And the

```
<servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
```

is not in any package?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to specify `<inin-param></init-param>` in `web.xml` file:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jahnvi</param-name>
    <param-value>abac</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And you have to specify code in servlet:

```
out.println("<h2>Init Parameters:</h2>");
Enumeration<String> initParams = getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames();
while (initParams.hasMoreElements()) 
{
    String paramName = initParams.nextElement();
    String paramValue = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(paramName);
    out.println(paramName + ": " + paramValue + "<br>");
}
```