# J2EE : how to download a file?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have currently a JSP page with a list of files and I would like download each file by a click on this name in the list.
My JSP code :

```
    <c:forEach var="listFiles" items="${listFiles}" varStatus="status">
       <span id="file-${status.index}" class="files">
           <a href="Download">
              <c:out value="${listFiles[status.index]}"></c:out>
           </a>
    </c:forEach>
```

I found a function for my servlet which run but it's a simple example where we give the path file to the servlet and I would I want this code be generic.
How to give each path file to the servlet ?

Comment: J2EE is a four letter word, it's now JEE.  J2EE refers to older enterprise edition versions which are mostly... frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

Put this code in your servlet :

```
String filename=null;

try
{
    filename = request.getParameter("filename");        

    if(filename == null || filename.equals(""))
    {
        throw new ServletException("File Name can't be null or empty");
    }

    String filepath = "yourDirPath"+filename;   //change your directory path

    File file = new File(filepath);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        throw new ServletException("File doesn't exists on server.");
    }

    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\""); 

    java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath);

    int i; 
    while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) 
    {
         response.getWriter().write(i); 
    } 
    fileInputStream.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.err.println("Error while downloading file["+filename+"]"+e);
}
```

Lets say your servlet url-pattern is : `download`

Now, your html code for downloading file should be something like this :

```
<a href="download?filename=YourFileName" target="_blank">Click here to download file</a>
```

Comment: It's better to expose an identifier to the client side which the server can decode into a filename, otherwise exposing and letting the client set the filename is a major security risk

Comment: Based on this question I assumed, he was learning so that I did not cover security portion.

Comment: Thanks, it's run ! But is there a way to have the path without write it in the servlet ? I have the same problem for the upload. It's not generic if I must write the path myself.

Comment: It might be beneficial to write something on what omerio said anyways, that way the OP can learn how to do this, and avoid starting bad habits such as plain file names.

Comment: @user3661334 There are lots of way.1)You can put directory path in your helper class which contins all your `static final String`. 2)You can load it from `config file`. 3)You can put it in servlet `init param`[how-to-retrieve-init-param-value-from-xml-to-servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682740/how-to-retrieve-init-param-value-from-xml-to-servlet). etc.

Comment: But your solutions can resolve my problem ? How an user of my application can upload a file, regardless of the directory ?

Comment: Do you want code for file upload??? Refer this link. [file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/07/ile-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp-java-web-tutorial-example.html)